# Error when trying to run jade file :for loop

Tags: pug

I am trying to run the following jade file and facing an error. Can some help please

```
extends layout
block content
    h1.
        Electronics
    div.left
        p Televisions


        -for(var i=0; i<10; ++i)
        {

        div.nameprod Name of TV : 
        for item in tryCSS 
            li
                a=item.description + item.type
        div.nameprod Company Name :  
        for item in tryCSS      
            li
                a= item.brand
        div.nameprod Size of TV : 
        for item in tryCSS  
            li
                a= item.size
        div.nameprod Color of TV : 
        for item in tryCSS 
            li
                a= item.color
        div.nameprod Features in TV :
        for item in tryCSS 
            li
                a= item.price
        }
```

i am getting the following error 
Please help

```
C:\node\nodetest1\views\tryCSS.jade:11 9| 10| -for(var i=0; i<10; ++i) > 11| { 12| 13| div.nameprod Name of TV : 14| for item in tryCSS unexpected text {

Error: C:\node\nodetest1\views\tryCSS.jade:11
9|         
10|         -for(var i=0; i<10; ++i)
```

> 11|         {
>       12|
>       13|         div.nameprod Name of TV : 
>       14|         for item in tryCSS

```
unexpected text {

at Object.Lexer.fail (C:\node\nodetest1\node_modules\jade\lib\lexer.js:816:11)
at Object.Lexer.next (C:\node\nodetest1\node_modules\jade\lib\lexer.js:875:15)
at Object.Lexer.lookahead (C:\node\nodetest1\node_modules\jade\lib\lexer.js:113:46)
at Parser.lookahead (C:\node\nodetest1\node_modules\jade\lib\parser.js:100:23)
at Parser.peek (C:\node\nodetest1\node_modules\jade\lib\parser.js:77:17)
at Parser.block (C:\node\nodetest1\node_modules\jade\lib\parser.js:685:30)
at Parser.tag (C:\node\nodetest1\node_modules\jade\lib\parser.js:800:26)
at Parser.parseTag (C:\node\nodetest1\node_modules\jade\lib\parser.js:719:17)
at Parser.parseExpr (C:\node\nodetest1\node_modules\jade\lib\parser.js:188:21)
at Parser.block (C:\node\nodetest1\node_modules\jade\lib\parser.js:689:25)
```

my jade file image below

![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqCcx.gif

Answer (score 1):

Jade uses indentation for blocks, not curly braces, even for JavaScript loops.  You should modify your code accordingly:

```
extends layout
block content
    h1.
        Electronics
    div.left
        p Televisions
        -for(var i=0; i<10; ++i)
            div.nameprod Name of TV : 
            for item in tryCSS 
                li
                    a=item.description + item.type
            div.nameprod Company Name :  
            for item in tryCSS      
                li
                    a= item.brand
            div.nameprod Size of TV : 
            for item in tryCSS  
                li
                    a= item.size
            div.nameprod Color of TV : 
            for item in tryCSS 
                li
                    a= item.color
            div.nameprod Features in TV :
            for item in tryCSS 
                li
                    a= item.price
```